# Ansible: Execute a sql script in multiple databases in rds

Tags: ansible

I am pretty new to ansible and I want to achieve the following as part of my work:

As part of regular deployment of our application, we have a `sql script`(which would alert tables, add tables etc) which needs to be run on 3 schema in a region and 5 schema in another. The application is in aws and the database is `arora db(RDS)`. My problem is I am not sure how do I parametrize  to make it run on each schema, first one after the other and then can upgrade that to run in parallel.

I did the following in a playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost

    vars:
    script_file: "{{ path }}"
    tasks:
      - name: rds_manage_user - run .sql script to alert and create new tables
    shell: "mysql -h {{ item.host }} -u {{ item.user }} -p{{ item.password }} < {{ script_file }} >> /usr/local/testscript.log"
    with_items:
        - { host: testhost1.com, user: testuser1, password: "testpass1" }
        - { host: testhost2.com, user: testuser2, password: "testpass2" }
```

This works and I get the desired output. But how do I pass these `hostname`, user and password from an external file and it can run through the file and get the script executed in all `schemas`.

Thanks a ton Ravi. It did work :) I have few follow up questions, as I am trying to iteratively improve on this script.

1. Can we make these 2 iterations run in parallel. In my case, this is very important as our sql deployment scripts do run for a considerable time.
2. If the sql script runs for say for example 3-4 hours as this might involve some update, modify to the existing schema, which has > 100k records, then would it fail or would it wait for it to complete and then move

How would we achieve the same using mysql_db module. Even this includes the above two questions regarding running in parallel and allow script to run for long times.
While trying using my_sqldb module I had written as below:

```
  vars:
    login_host: "{{ host }}"
    login_user: "{{ user }}"
    login_password: "{{ password }}"
    login_name: "{{ name }}"
    script_file: "{{ path }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Run SQL commands
      mysql_db:
        login_host: "{{ login_host }}"
        login_password: "{{ login_password }}"
        login_user: "{{ login_user }}"
        name: "{{login_name }}"
        state: import
        target: "{{ script_file }}"
      register: sql_query_output
```

Comment: You should have probably asked the extra questions as separate questions and just add a link to this one, because now you already have an accepted answer, so people are going to skip the question.

Comment: @JamesZ: Thanks for the input. I was bit confused and ended up putting in both places. Would take care henceforth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can defined variable file and add those details in it and pass it to your playbook.

```
contents of dbdata.yaml 
###########
---

conn_details:
    - { host: testhost1.com, user: testuser1, password: "testpass1" }
    - { host: testhost2.com, user: testuser2, password: "testpass2" }
############
```

In playbook, make changes are below.
contents of playbook:

```
#########
vars:
script_file: "{{ path }}"
vars_files:
  - dbdata.yaml 
# for above file, you can provide absolute of path of file if it is not kept in current folder
tasks:
  - name: rds_manage_user - run .sql script to alert and create new tables
shell: "mysql -h {{ item.host }} -u {{ item.user }} -p{{ item.password }} < {{ script_file }} >> /usr/local/testscript.log"
with_items: "{{ conn_details }}"
##########
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Ravi. It did work :)
I have few follow up questions, as I am trying to iteratively improve on this script.
1. Can we make these 2 iterations run in parallel. In my case, this is very important as our sql deployment scripts do run for a considerable time.
2. If the sql script runs for say for example 3-4 hours as this might involve some update, modify to the existing schema, which has lakhs of records, then would it fail or would it wait for it to complete and then move.

Comment: Yes. you can. Please refer: https://toptechtips.github.io/2019-07-09-ansible_run_playbooks_tasks_in_parallel/ . Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Ravi for the help. It did work. I tweaked to suite my needs as below.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late post. Thanks to @Ravi for the help. I extended the above piece provided by him to execute few tasks in parallel in localhost. Only change introduced is in the ansible playbook. I am reproducing the playbook as is below:

```
 hosts: localhost

  vars:
    script_file: "{{ path }}"
  vars_files:
    - dbdata.yml
  tasks:
  - name: execute sql script
    shell: "mysql -h {{ item.host }} -u {{ item.user }} -p{{ item.password }} < {{ script_file }} >> /usr/local/testscript.log"
    with_items: "{{ conn_details }}"
    register: sql_query_output
    async: 600
    poll: 0

  - name: Wait for creation to finish
    async_status:
      jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
    register: _jobs
    until: _jobs.finished
    delay: 5  # Check every 5 seconds. Adjust as you like.
    retries: 10
    with_items: "{{ sql_query_output.results }}"
```

Hope this helps.